# Case sensitivity in Pascal (using Integer as example)

Tags: delphi, pascal

My understanding is that since Delphi 2009, the compiler only accepts the data type `Integer`. However, there are plenty of articles such as [example 1](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pascal/pascal_data_types.htm) and [example 2](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Variables_and_Data_Types) showing mixed (!) usage of `integer` and `Integer`. AFAIK, [Embarcadero websites](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.Integer) exclusively uses `Integer` (good!) but the [Wikipedia article on Pascal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_(programming_language)) exclusively uses `integer`.

Unfortunately, I do not have access to another Pascal compiler, but Delphi 7 accepts both `integer` and `Integer`:

```
int1: Integer;
int2: intEGER;          // Allowed in Delphi 7
struct1: MyRecord;
struct2: mYrEcOrD;      // Also allowed => source of bugs!
```

Can someone enlighten me on whether Pascal is officially case-sensitive or not and whether this changes with the latest Delphi compilers.

Comment: The only thing case-sensitive in Delphi is string comparisons (AFAIK). Nothing else.

Comment: Your understanding is wrong, as @DavidHeffernan has pointed out.

Comment: @MartynA: OK, good to learn that. Not sure how I got it into my head that later versions of Delphi were case-sensitive. Bit of a shame as case-sensitivity is a useful feature.

Comment: Your understanding is 100% mistaken. The one and only instance where Delphi is case-sensitive is when using `procedure Register;` to register components, where the precise case is required.

Comment: Most of the best Delphi websites I use (such as DelpiBasics, http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/) consistently use `Integer` but there are tonnes of examples out there with the lowercase example.

Comment: I suggest that you avoid DelphiBasics. It is of very variable quality and often outdated. The documentation definitively states the rules here. My answer links to the docs.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your understanding is amiss. All versions of Delphi accept any capitalization of any data type and any other identifier, except in cases of external interoperability, such as importing symbols from a DLL.

Comment: You don't have to take my word for it. Ask the compiler and see for yourself.

Answer (score 9):

Contrary to your statements, Pascal is not case sensitive. So `Integer` and `integer` are the same identifier.

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Fundamental_Syntactic_Elements#Identifiers) states this as follows:

> Since the Delphi Language is case-insensitive, an identifier like `CalculateValue` could be written in any of these ways:
>
> ```
> CalculateValue
> calculateValue
> calculatevalue
> CALCULATEVALUE
> ```

The Wikipedia article you link to in the question says:

> Letter case is ignored in Pascal source.

The fact that some authors prefer a particular capitalisation in no way implies that the compiler treats different capitalisations as being different identifiers. It does not.

Of course, most experienced Pascal developers will use consistent capitalisation. Code is easier to read when it is consistent and capitalisation, for instance when using the Pascal case naming convention, conveys meaning to the reader.

To me this is motivation for languages being designed to be case sensitive. As a general rule, if the developer cares about something then it is often helpful for the compiler to care about it too. That way the compiler can check that the developer does not make mistakes. But case insensitivity for Pascal was determined long ago and for reasons of compatibility will not ever change.